# Query to get data from two tables using GROUP_CONCAT from one table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data from two tables table members and table membersupdate below query is working fine but it takes long time to get data.
Please help me to resolve the issue in query.

Below is the sample of two tables and expected output.

My members table.

| mobile | name | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234566 | Mukesh | 9/30/2021 10:03:51 AM |
| 7777737 | Arun | 9/30/2021 10:03:22 AM |
| 8768938 | Kapil | 9/30/2021 12:16:02 PM |
| 2309877 | Rajesh | 9/30/2021 10:03:45 AM |
| 7087653 | Manish | 9/30/2021 10:03:32 AM |
| 1818736 | Umesh | 9/30/2021 10:03:45 AM |
| 0987929 | Anil | 9/30/2021 10:04:01 AM |

My membersupdate table.

| mobile | disposition | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234566 | Not Contactable | 2021-09-30 17:04:08 |
| 1234566 | Client Hung up | 2021-09-30 18:04:32 |
| 7777737 | Not Contactable | 2021-09-30 11:49:32 |
| 7777737 | Not interested | 2021-09-30 12:00:46 |
| 8768938 | Not interested | 2021-09-30 12:00:46 |
| 8768938 | Unworked | 2021-09-30 17:05:41 |
| 2309877 | Follow up | 2021-09-30 13:49:16 |
| 2309877 | Not Contactable | 2021-09-30 14:25:27 |
| 7087653 | Not Contactable | 2021-09-30 18:44:38 |
| 7087653 | Follow up | 2021-09-30 18:51:57 |
| 1818736 | No. out of service | 2021-09-30 12:14:38 |
| 1818736 | Follow up | 2021-09-30 12:31:36 |
| 0987929 | Not Contactable | 2021-09-30 14:15:17 |
| 0987929 | Not interested | 2021-09-30 17:45:26 |

output:-

| mobile | Name | date_created | History |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234566 | Mukesh | 9/30/2021 10:03 | Not Contactable, 2021-09-30 17:04:08, Client Hung up, 2021-09-30 18:04:32 |
| 7777737 | Arun | 9/30/2021 10:03 | Not Contactable, 2021-09-30 11:49:32, Not interested, 2021-09-30 12:00:46 |
| 8768938 | Kapil | 9/30/2021 12:16 | Unworked, 2021-09-30 17:05:41, Not Contactable, 2021-09-30 17:23:23 |
| 2309877 | Rajesh | 9/30/2021 10:03 | Follow up, 2021-09-30 13:49:16, Not Contactable, 2021-09-30 14:25:27 |
| 7087653 | Manish | 9/30/2021 10:03 | Not Contactable, 2021-09-30 18:44:38, Follow up, 2021-09-30 18:51:57 |
| 1818736 | Umesh | 9/30/2021 10:03 | No. out of service , 2021-09-30 12:14:38, Follow up, 2021-09-30 12:31:36 |
| 0987929 | Anil | 9/30/2021 10:04 | Not Contactable, 2021-09-30 14:15:17, Not interested, 2021-09-30 17:45:26 |

Below is the query I am using.

```
SELECT c . * , GROUP_CONCAT(p.disposition,', ',p.timestamp SEPARATOR ', ') as History 
FROM members c,membersupdate p 
WHERE c.mobile = p.mobile and Date(date_created) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' 
GROUP BY c.mobile"
```

Comment: *but it takes long time to get data* Optimization question needs in complete CREATE TABLE scripts and EXPLAIN output at least.

Comment: ```Date(date_created) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'``` is wrong from the optimization looking point. Remove function usage - the column in WHERE expression must be used directly. Use 2 unequiations instead of BETWEEN.